# Maven not recognized when running shell as admin

Tags: maven

I use mvn to compile a project in Windows 10. It tries to create folder in C: and I get access denied error. When I try to run the shell as admin I get "mvn is not recognized as ..." error. What can be a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add your maven installation directory to your system's path.
There are 2 options to do so:
1. Add the maven path to your current CMD path

```
PATH=%PATH%;<mavenpath>
```

Note: this only works on your actual cmd window, at close that change will be lost

2. Add the maven path to your system's path permanently, go to Windows properties, Advanced system configuration -> Environment variables -> System variables.

You can use this page as reference to do the second option, (is for Java but still works if you change the java path for the maven path) https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml